# How to change any by all in active admin collection data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I am using collection for filter data.

> filter :"status" , :as => :select, :collection => User::STATUS

I want to change default option label any by all.
[image]

How to do it in active admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use option `prompt`

ex,

```
filter :"status" , :as => :select, :collection => User::STATUS, prompt: 'All'
```

Hope it will Help you.